# Agregar datos a un combobox desde otro formulario

Tags: c#

Tengo dos formulario, en uno tengo un `ComboBox` el cual en el evento `Load` me carga datos desde una base de datos sql server realizando una consulta.

Para agregar mas datos tendría que modificar mi consulta, lo cual agregué un botón adelante del `ComboBox`, al darle click me abre un pequeño formulario donde están todos los registro de una tabla de sql server. Quiero que cuando se seleccione uno me lo agregue al combo del primer formulario, como lo puedo implementar?

```
da.Fill(TABLA);
cmbProductos.DataSource = null;
cmbProductos.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
cmbProductos.ValueMember = "id";
cmbProductos.DataSource = TABLA;
```

Así cargo mis datos en el `ComboBox` en un principio, esto solo funcionaria mientras no cierro el formulario principal, por que cuando se vuelve a cargar solo aparecerán los datos de la consulta...

Así obtengo los campos que quiero agregar al otro formulario:

```
string concepto;
string id;
filaSeleccionada = dgvAgregarCombo.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
concepto = dgvAgregarCombo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CONCEPTO"].Value.ToString();
id = dgvAgregarCombo.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID_CONCEPTO"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Tu evento load se ejecuta cada vez que cargas ese formulario. Como ese formulario ya esta cargado cuando abrís el otro, tu mejor opción dado lo que planteas, es sacar del evento load la carga del combo y pasarla a un método, y también, luego que volves de la carga secundaria, volver a llenar el combo.

Para ello, move el código que carga el combo en el evento load a un método:

```
Private void LlenarCombo()
{
    ...
    da.Fill(TABLA);
    cmbProductos.DataSource = null;
    cmbProductos.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
    cmbProductos.ValueMember = "id";
    cmbProductos.DataSource = TABLA;
}
```

Y en el load de tu form reemplaza el código que carga el combo por una llamada a esa función.

También, agrega a la vuelta de la carga en el otro formulario, una llamada a esta función para que vuelva a cargar el combo.

Comment: no debería ser `public`?

Comment: Para nada.. no es llamado por el otro form.. en el metodo que llama al segundo form, a la vuelta, se llama a este metodo. Es mas el otro form podria informar si hubo un agregado o no (capaz cancelo) y entonces no deberia llamarse a este metodo.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa com parametro un datatable

```
Datatable dt = New Datatable();
//llenas el datatable
Form Frm = new MyFrm(dt);
Frm.ShowDialog();
//En el otro form tomas el Datatable
```